# linear independence and reduced row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If I can write vectors $(2,0,0)$ ,$ (1,-1,0)$ and $(0,1,1) $

as $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ using reduced row echelon form does this means that they are linearly indepedent of each other?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1, v_2, ... , v_n$ be a collection of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Form the $ n \times n$ matrix $A$ whose columns are these $v_i$ $(1 \leq i \leq n)$: $A = (v_1 \hspace{5mm}v_2 \hspace{5mm} \cdots \hspace{5mm} v_n)$.

Then, the following statements are equivalent:
\begin{array}
(\text{(a) The rows and columns of } A \text{ are linearly independent,} \\
\text{(b) The rows and columns of } A \text{ span  } \mathbb{R}^n, \\
\text{(c) The rows and columns of } A \text{ form a basis of } \mathbb{R}^n, \\
\text{(d) The determinant of } A \text{ is nonzero.}
\end{array}

(Mathematics for Economists, C. Simon and L. Blume, p. 248)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the reduced-row-echelon form of the matrix whose columns are your vectors, is correct, since it reduced to the identity matrix, your vectors are indeed linearly independent.